# Getting execution date on an operator in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I created an operator I want to use.

On the execute method I'm calling a function that requiers a date for when to run, but I just haven't been able to get the date.
I could use a `datetime.now` but that would not work for when I need to reprocess the past.

On the operator I need to have:

```
def execute(self, context):
  log.info("Starting my example function")

  running_date = 'How do I get the date?  :('
  example_function(running_date)

  log.info("The function ran for date" + str(running_date))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code snippet, I assume you are interested in a PythonOperator.
If you set `provide_context=True` when you create the operator and you have the signature of the function accepting `**kwargs`, then you can have access to the execution date from within the function through `kwargs['execution_date']`.

```
def execute(self, **kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']
    ...

PythonOperator(
    task_id='execution_date_task_example',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=execute,
    ...
)
```

Comment: I am currently using the BaseOperator, if I change that to PythonOperator I'd be able to do that? I currently get nothing in kwargs

Comment: Sorry, my assumption was wrong, I didn’t remember about the BaseOperator. `context` in your execute function should have the same structure as kwargs though. So you should be able to do context['execution_date']. I will edit my answer later today.